# Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService when launching GRID through SSH, but works fine when GRID created directly on host

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

For our testing/execution needs, we have a Windows Server 2012 R2 VM where we have `.bat` scripts for setting up a Selenium Enterprise Grid Hub and a Chrome Node.

Now when I set up the Grid and Node using these scripts by directly logging in to the VM, test execution proceeds as normal. However, If I do the set up by invoking the same batch scripts remotely using an SSH call, I get the following:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:32:19.891Z'
System info: host: 'TWV-BWN-A002', ip:, os.name: 'Windows Server 2012 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Command duration or timeout: 212 milliseconds
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$new$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:123)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:138)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:219)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:155)
    at com.fanniemae.lai.testauto.selenium.utils.WebConnector.getRemoteChromeDriver(WebConnector.java:74)
    at com.fanniemae.lai.testauto.selenium.alteryx.AlteryxStepDefinition.setup(AlteryxStepDefinition.java:46)
```

I am using selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0 along with chromedriver version 2.38 and Chrome 69.

Things I have tried doing so far is adding the location of the chromedriver.exe binary to the system `PATH`. Also added a webdriver.chrome.driver system environment variable to hold the location of the same.

When launching the GRID either by directly logging in to the VM, or by SSH remote invocation of the scripts, I am able t access the ip:port/grid/console successfully. Hence at this point, I am unable to see what the problem could be. anyone faced something similar?

Answer (score 3):

Despite having the Chromedriver.exe binary on the path, and also provided as a system environment variable, I went ahead and passed it with its absolute path as a parameter to selenium standalone server jar and viola! It worked!

java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:/full/path/to/chromedriver.exe -jar C:/full/path/to/selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar -role node -hub http://ip:port/grid/register -browser "browserName=chrome, version=ANY, maxInstances=10, platform=WINDOWS"

Comment: Had to do this on a remote controlled linux machine, because I have no idea how to set a variable in a calling process process-block simply in any kind of scaleable fashion. Thank you Hasan.

Comment: @Conrad were you able to get it to work following Hasan's answer? I have listed the Dwebdriver path but the driver is still not found

Comment: @mastercool I am using python bindings and a module called webdriver_manager which gives me the exact binary path ~ pseudo code like this
driver_path = ChromeDriverManager().install()
exec(["java.exe", f"-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver={driver_path}", "-jar", "C:\Users\cb\.wdm\drivers\selenium-server-standalone\ALL\3.141\selenium-server-standalone.jar" "-host", "172.22.0.13", "-port", "4444"])
this approach also worked on a linuxy machine

Comment: Turns out l was trying to use a windows chrome driver on my Linux machine. Fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

As per the configuration you have mentioned in your question you are using:

- selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0
- ChromeDriver version 2.38
- Chrome v69.x

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.38*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.38*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.38/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v65-67**

- You are using *chrome=69.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v2.42*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.42/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v68-70**

So there is a clear mismatch between the *ChromeDriver v2.38* and the *Chrome Browser v69.0*

### Solution

- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.14.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.42**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version between ***Chrome v68-70*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.42 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.42/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.

Comment: Thank you very much "New Contributor".